# PHP8 does not get the data i send via POST (fetch javascript, php8)

Tags: javascript, fetch

php8 does not get the data i send. I get an error when i try to insert a new song into my api.
in console i got an object with POST, its value is an empry array.

```js
fetch("http://localhost/api.audio-player/",{
   method: 'POST',
   body:formData,
   headers: {
       "enctype":"multipart/form-data",
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then(res=>(res.ok)?res.json():Promise.reject(res.statusText))
.then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.error("Error: "+err||"Desconocido");
});
```

i have this code in the front.

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="POST"){
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "POST"=>$_POST
        )
    );  
}

?>
```

PD: I use $_POST in this example, but i will send image and audio, so i need to use $_FILES too
PD: I am using xampp

Comment: and what does devtools shows the response is?

Comment: i do not have installed it (shall not). If works for you, the console shows a object with the prop "POST" and it is a empty array

Comment: devtools is part of any modern browser....

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` line. Deleting it has solved